# Include method doesn't work on ef core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

After migrating from ef core 2.2 to 3.1 my query stopped including related entities.
The code :

```
 using (var dbContext = new JobManagerContext(_options))
            {
                var t = await dbContext.JobsBulkDbSet
                    .Where(i => i.Uuid == uuid)
                    .Select(b => new
                    {
                        bulk = b,
                        jobs = dbContext.JobDbSet.Include(x => x.UpgradeJobs).Where(x => x.JobsBulkEntityUuid == b.Uuid)
                    })
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                return SetJobs(t.bulk, t.jobs);
            }
```

The query returns the JobDbSet entities but each entity has null on UpgradeJobs property.
Does anyone know how I can include UpgradeJobs in the result ?
Thanks

Comment: You're still running this query in ef-core 2. In ef-core 3 this wouldn't run without `ToList` added to the query for `jobs` and the `Include` would work.

Comment: Hi @user1977367, could you please share your model design?